# Postfix, Dovecot and Spamassassin unexpectedely fill-ups my disk usage

Tags: postfix, centos7, dovecot, spamassassin

I am on VPS using CentOS 7, LAMP using Postfix, Dovecot and Spamassassin with Rainloop as my email client. When I have started Postfix using:

```
systemctl enable postfix  
systemctl restart postfix
```

and Dovecot as:

```
systemctl restart dovecot  
systemctl enable dovecot
```

After that my CPU usage goes above 90-99% as well my disk usage start fill-up unexpectedely as well as I am only able to send email and not being able to receive emails. Here is some outputs when I am running this command:

```
    [root@server ~]# postconf -nf
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps  
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases  
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes  
command_directory = /usr/sbin  
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix  
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix  
debug_peer_level = 2  
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd  
    $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5  
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1  
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks  
html_directory = no  
inet_interfaces = all  
inet_protocols = all  
mail_owner = postfix  
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix  
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man  
message_size_limit = 30720000  
meta_directory = /etc/postfix  
milter_default_action = accept  
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain  
myhostname = mail.myhostname.com  
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8  
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix  
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters  
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps  
    $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains  
    $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps  
    $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks  
    $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps  
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix  
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix3-3.5.8/README_FILES  
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix3-3.5.8/samples  
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix  
setgid_group = postdrop  
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix  
smtp_tls_security_level = may  
smtpd_data_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:/var/log/policyServerSocket  
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891  
smtpd_policy_service_default_action = DUNNO  
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,  
    reject_unauth_destination  
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes  
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes  
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth  
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot  
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem  
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem  
smtpd_use_tls = yes  
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map  
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550  
virtual_alias_domains =  
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf,  
    mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf  
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000  
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail  
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf  
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf  
virtual_transport = dovecot  
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
```

AS well as when running:

```
    [root@server ~]# postconf -Mf
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions  
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps  
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd  
    -o content_filter=spamassassin  
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd  
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission  
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt  
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes  
    -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no  
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject  
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING  
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd  
    -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps  
    -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes  
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes  
    -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no  
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions  
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject  
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING  
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup  
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup  
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr  
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr  
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite  
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce  
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify  
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush  
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap  
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap  
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp  
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp  
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq  
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error  
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error  
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard  
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local  
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual  
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp  
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil  
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache  
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu  
    user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d  
    ${recipient}  
spamassassin unix -      n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DROhu  
    user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f  
    ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}  
spamassassin unix -      n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R  
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender}  
    ${recipient}
```

Finally, when I stopped Postfix and Dovecot then my Disk Usage stops fill-ups but when I again start Postfix and Dovecot then again Disk usage start fill-ups.
I am appreciating for any help to fix this issue; if something more needed to analyze this issue then I can shows at here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter:

postfix is warning you that you are using some parameter in one file (in master.cf) that is not defined (in main.cf).

First figure out how that happened, fix that, then deal with any remaining problems.

One way this might have happened would be that you inadvertently truncated the file and that is why you are missing parts of your configurations, including the parameters now triggering the warning.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, due to covid-19 pandemic, one of my family member got infected so I  comes today. I am new with VPS; here I have posted my both master.cf and main.cf contents to review Please

Answer (score -1):

Here is the contents of master.cf

```
[root@server ~]# cd /etc/postfix/
```

[root@server postfix]# cat master.cf

## Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format

## of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").

## Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.

## ==========================================================================

## service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args

## (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)

## ==========================================================================

smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/submission
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp

## -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5

showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

## ====================================================================

## Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual

## pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.

## Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery

## agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}

## and other message envelope options.

## ====================================================================

## maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.

## Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1

#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

## ====================================================================

## Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.

## Specify in cyrus.conf:

## lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4

## Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:

## mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost

## virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost

## ====================================================================

## Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)

## Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1

#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}

## ====================================================================

## Old example of delivery via Cyrus.

#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}

## ====================================================================

## See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.

#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

## ====================================================================

## Other external delivery methods.

#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)

#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient

#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe

## flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store

## ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}

#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

## flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py

## ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e  /usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe flags=R user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

Here is the contents of main.cf

```
[root@server postfix]# cat main.cf
```

## Global Postfix configuration file. This file lists only a subset

## of all parameters. For the syntax, and for a complete parameter

## list, see the postconf(5) manual page (command: "man 5 postconf").

## For common configuration examples, see BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README

## and STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README. To find these documents, use

## the command "postconf html_directory readme_directory", or go to

## http://www.postfix.org/.

## For best results, change no more than 2-3 parameters at a time,

## and test if Postfix still works after every change.

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix3-3.5.8/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix3-3.5.8/README_FILES

myhostname = mail.myhostname.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_tls_security_level = may

smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtpd_data_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:/var/log/policyServerSocket
smtpd_policy_service_default_action = DUNNO

tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map

[root@server postfix]# cd

Please review it and make me sure that where I have made mistake and help me to fix this issue. I am appreciating for the help to fix this issue.
Thanks